# AWS Amplify -- Cannot iteratively rollback as the following step does not contain a previousMetaKey: {"status":"WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"}

Tags: aws-amplify-cli

Summary:
When attempting to `amplify push` changes to my graphql api via the Amplify CLI after aborting an `amplify push` (using ctrl-c) the cli complains that there is a deployment in progress and cannot deploy.

First error message:

```
A deployment is in progress.
If the prior rollback was aborted, run:
`amplify push --iterative-rollback` to rollback the prior deployment
`amplify push --force` to re-deploy
```

Both of those suggested commands result in:

```
✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Cannot iteratively rollback as the following step does not contain a previousMetaKey: {"status":"WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"}
An error occurred during the push operation: Cannot iteratively rollback as the following step does not contain a previousMetaKey: {"status":"WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"}
```

All deployments in the Amplify Admin UI show as completed.

I tried `amplify pull`, `amplify env pull`, `amplify pull --restore` (all of which override your local changes - heads up). None worked to solve my problem. Still could not `amplify push`.

I finally found this idea: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-adminui/issues/172#issuecomment-819784558

**Solution**

Deleting the `deployment-state.json` file as suggested in that reply allowed me to perform `amplify push` again. If you open it up you'll see that this is where the cli must be seeing the  `{"status":"WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"}`

Sharing my solution here in case someone else has the same problem!

Answer (score 41):

**Solution**

Deleting the `deployment-state.json` file as suggested in that reply allowed me to perform amplify push again. If you open it up you'll see that this is where the cli must be seeing the `{"status":"WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"}`.

Sharing my solution here in case someone else has the same problem!

Comment: For those who are wondering where deployment-state.json is, it is not in your local amplify directory. In order to find it, open amplify-meta.json and find your DeploymentBucketName. deployment-state.json should be in that bucket.

Comment: Also worked for me, only my bucket name was in amplify/team-provider-info.json

Comment: If like me don't have `deployment-state.json` in your `./amplify` folder, and there is nothing about it in `amplify-meta.json`, you have to go in `AWS S3` open your amplify bucket and you'll find 
 there. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/9665#issuecomment-1042723904

Comment: Can't edit this thread(too many pending edits) but this is not a local file, but a file in your s3 bucket that should has a suffix of "deployment"

Answer (score 9):

Open the corresponding s3 bucket to the Amplify app.. usually begins with "Amplify-appname...." and delete the "deployment-state.json" file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anything changed with debugging this error, but I experienced this today, and needed to go into the S3 bucket associated with my Amplify project and delete the `deployment-state.json` file, not than the `amplify-meta.json` file for this amplify cli error to go away and for `amplify push` to work correctly.

I noticed that the `deployment-state.json` file in the S3 bucket has a structure with the following values:

```json
{
  "version": "1",
  "startedAt": "2023-06-20T00:00:00.000Z",
  "status": "DEPLOYING",
  "currentStepIndex": 0,
  "steps": [
    {
      "status": "WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"
    },
    {
      "status": "WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"
    },
    {
      "status": "WAITING_FOR_DEPLOYMENT"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you see these step values in a pending state like this, the amplify CLI will think a deployment is happening or in the midst of happening. Perhaps deleting this file is what prompts amplify to accept updates to your cloudformation stack.